# Unit testing with Jest and Sequelize - Test passing when it shouldn't

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, sequelize.js

I'm trying to write some unit tests, and at first they appeared to be working, but then I realized some of them were passing when they definitely shouldn't be, and I've included one such example from my code of a test passing when it shouldn't:

**controller.js**

```
const userModel = require('../models').users;

module.exports = {
    async getUserByID(req, res) {
        try {
            var user = await userModel.findOne({
                where: { id: req.params.id }
            });
            res.status(201).send(user);
        catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**controller.test.js**

```
const controller = require('../controllers/controller');
const httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');

//mock for main model that my controller function uses
jest.mock('../models/users', () => {
    const SequelizeMock = require('sequelize-mock');
    const dbMock = new SequelizeMock();
    return dbMock.define('users', {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Tony',
        email: 'test1@gmail.com',
        uid: '12345'
    })
});

//mock for model that's associated to my users model
jest.mock('../models/user_prefs', () => {
    const SequelizeMock = require('sequelize-mock');
    const dbMock = new SequelizeMock();
    return dbMock.define('user_prefs', {
        id: 1,
        uid: '12345',
        notification_settings: {}
    })
});

//the actual test
describe('getUserByID', () => {
    it('should get user from mock', () => {
        var req = httpMocks.createRequest({
            params: {
                id: 1
            }
        });

        var res = httpMocks.createResponse();

        controller.getUserByID(req, res).then(function(user) {
            expect(user.name).toEqual('Steve');
        })
    });
});
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.js --forceExit --coverage"
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: "node"
}
```

When I run `npm test` everything runs just fine, but it tells me that the test passes, even though it obviously shouldn't if it was correctly retrieving the data from the mock, and I can't really figure out why.

Comment: Most likely the expectation's not being hit inside the test. Try `expect(false).toBe(true)` and see. You should read https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous.

Comment: Looking at that documentation, that looks like exactly what's happening. I'll try that out and take a look at the docs, thanks so much